# How to be found by headhunters?

Tags: recruitment

In scientific conferences and online communities such as linkedin, there are many headhunters who recruit professional for employers. I wonder how one can expose himself that he is open to new offers? For example, the following approaches were not practical in my case:

- Changing linkedin status to *looking for new opportunity*: but this
  is something that unemployed people do. I mean when one has a job but
  considering special offers.
- Posting resume on job websites: in my experience, offers are not
  serious or relevant.

Sometimes, I wonder if this headhunting business is serious at all. Where and how effectively attract the attention of headhunters by showing openness to special offers?

Comment: Why is changing a linkedin status to "looking for new opportunity" only for the unemployed? I think it would apply for people who are employed but are also looking for a new opportunity. Just because you're being selective about new opportunities doesn't mean you're not looking.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner When using linkedin for professional networking and collaboration, it is better (and somehow necessary) to keep the current position on the top.

Comment: I don't think changing your status will make you look unemployed if your current position's "end date" reads "Present". If you don't set your linkedin status to "looking for new..." how will recruiters know that you're actually looking?

Comment: Trust me all it takes is to get one well connected head hunter to know you are looking... so give one a call.

Comment: Just one thing - be good, reaally good. If you are they will find you. If you just want to change your current work, as you stated - change your status in Linkedin.

Answer (score 2):

Your profile needs to have fairly detailed experience items - I have things like C#, SQL Server, Microsoft Access/VBA, etc. on mine, and I have a lot of endorsements. You need to have membership in relevant groups, such as, in my case, Microsoft .NET, SQL Server, Access, etc. and contribute content to those groups, particularly answering questions.  In short, you're an active participant in forums.  This will give hiring managers and recruiters the feeling you are a significant actor in your space.

I also go to MeetUps in my locality, and follow up with people I meet at these. This is physical face to face networking, but this eventually percolates into the LinkedIn references. On a number of occasions I brought someone over to install SQL Server Express on their laptops so that they could start learning the database, when they see requests for endorsements with my name on them they tend to say 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

I get inquiries every few days via the resume posting sites and LinkedIn. I have no idea how serious they are, but one way to get more offers is to freshen your resume/profile on the site.

Many times people don't want to change their status to looking for a new opportunity because that would alert their current employer that they are looking.  I hadn't realized that the opposite is also true, that only the unemployed or those who were given notice would set this status.

If you are willing to alert your current employer by setting your status to looking, then do so. It shows a willingness to switch jobs.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those YMMV questions. I think it depends heavily on exactly what it is that you do. Based on my experience as a developer, the following works:

- At least a basic linked in profile with connections from your previous jobs. In my opinion, you don't even need to bother with endorsements. Connections will be sufficient.
- Post a resume to one of the big job websites in your area.
- Make sure to have the silly buzzwords that are relevant to what you do in both of the above. Don't underestimate the power of this. I've worked with a serious recruiter that scored a few good offers for me, and once asked over lunch "So is C++ a different thing from C#?" Buzzwords is how these people work.
- Finally, make sure that you leave every job on good terms. The world has become a global village. After a while, past employers or people you have worked with will be reaching out to you as well. I've certainly done this when I needed people for my teams (to see if they are looking, or if they could recommend someone).

The above generates a couple of calls per week for me. Most of them, as you have pointed out, are garbage. However occasionally I've had interesting jobs come my way (the ratio is maybe 20-1). You have to accept that the economic incentive for recruiters is to send everything to everyone based on keyword matches, and it is up to you to sift through it. There will be a few gems buried in the spam, don't despair.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it's as simple as approaching a headhunter or a recruiting agency and registering with them so they can be your "agent" in your job search. If you have a background that's suitable for the clients they work with, chances are high that they'd be happy to hear from you.

Headhunters make money from their clients by providing top talent that the clients wouldn't otherwise have access to. So you're right - putting your resume on general job boards might not do the trick. If you're in a field that has specialized job boards for its niche (like Careers 2.0 for programming jobs), you can post your resume there so hiring companies can reach out to you directly, thus skipping the need for a headhunter altogether.